# Верна постановка восклицательного знака?

Tags: пунктуация

Приглашаем принять участие в конкурсе «Мини Мисс...»!

Answer (score 2):

Восклицательный знак в данном предложении очень даже возможен, у него конкретная функция: предложение становится восклицательным, интонация призывная, радостно-доброжелательная.

Comment: "Приглашаем принять участие" - канцелярский стиль,  произнести его призывно-радостно очень сложно.

Comment: Пусть призывно, но радостно-то с чего бы? Функция знака следует за содержанием, а не наоборот. Ну а вообще, если одного мало, надо три знака влепить, и будет бодренько.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что восклицательный знак для такого предложения **не подойдет.**

Согласно правилам, **восклицательный знак ставится в предложениях особой структуры, где возможна восклицательная интонация** (к примеру, побудительные предложения).

[Розенталь. § 3. Восклицательный знак](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=89#pp89)

Например:  **Участвуйте в конкурсе и выигрывайте призы!  Участвуйте в конкурсе u побеждайте! Приглашаем всех!**